# Display another Div when hover another Div's child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to display a div when hover another div's child

Here is my HTML code

```
<div id='container'>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li class='hover'>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='hover' id='display'>some text</div>
</div>
```

and my jquery code

```
$(".hover").hover(function () {
    $('#display').show();
}, function () {
    $('#display').hide();
});
```

it works fine but if i add time to javascript code for animation purpose, like

```
show(200);
hide(200);
```

it looks funny. So if there is someone who could tell me on how to fix this i really would appreciate.

Comment: Please explain 'funny'.

Comment: sorry for not being clear, if I hover "A" then move to "some text" it hides then shows again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because new animation it triggered before last have ended.

The simpliest fix is to add stop();

```
 $(".hover").hover(function () {
     $('#display').stop();
     $('#display').show(200);   
 }, function () {
      $('#display').stop();
     $('#display').hide(100);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/igos/Ck9hv/